# mysqlpump how to ignore database's name?

Tags: mysql

`mysqlpump`'s backup has database's name like:

```sql
INSERT INTO `database`.`table` ...
```

how to ignore database's name?

why I do not use `mysqldump`? because `mysqldump` will back up definer of `view` and I don't want it. useing `mysqldump` can ignore definer of `view`.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have mysqlpump ignore the definer with the "--skip-definer" option.

Unfortunately, I have not found a way to have it ignore the db name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).